# Why does these lines of code freeze the Scala/SBT build?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

Transitioning from Play Framework 2.1 to 2.2 (Scala) I was restructuring some code and found some lines of code to totally freeze the SBT build until the process was killed due to `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. Also Eclipse (tried with Juno and Kepler but I doubt it has anything to do with this) froze and it didn't even load the workbench anymore.

So, here's the code. I would love to know what makes the compiler to freeze and not just give an error here.

```
def foo = Action { implicit request =>
  someForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => Ok,
    form => Async { Future.successful(Ok) }
    )
}
```

I solved the issue already, but I'm curious why this just freezes everything. I'm on a Mac running java (1.7.0_40).

**Update:** Also, I'm using Scala 2.10.2. A coworker of mine can compile this on his PC, but with deprecation warnings on Async.

Comment: I have no explanation but I got the same kind of problem while migrating to 2.2, compilation crawling to a halt and finally an out of memory exception, but after changing it into Action.async across the app everything was compiling just fine again.

Comment: That's what I did too, but just for the sake of being curious about every tiny bit of technical detail, I'd love to know what makes the build hang. A bug in the scala compiler?

Comment: Can you file a bug report? We'd also need more information to solve this, e.g. thread dumps.

Comment: For those reading along, one thing to try would be upgrading to the latest Scala version (currently 2.10.4). See: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Howto/scala.html

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this as soon as I can and I'll gladly file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain expressions within Scala that when you ask the compiler to evaluate them, it will instantiate a TON of type instances trying to figure out the unified difference between two types.   Most likely, the type you're returning is NOT what you expect.

I would explicitly annotate the result type:

```
def foo = Action { implicit request =>
  someForm.bindFromRequest.fold[Result](
    formWithErrors => Ok,
    form => Async { Future.successful(Ok) }
  )
}
```

This should help the type inferencer KNOW what the types are and only check to see if they match, rather than expand infinitely.  Also, sounds like it may have been a scala compiler bug.